# jquery zoom external image from text link (solved with js)

Tags: jquery, magnify

I am currently using jquery to zoom images.

```
<figure>
    <img src="images/normal/bambit2.jpg" class="magnify" alt="Bambi-aiheisia koriste-esineitä" />
    <figcaption class="kuvateksti">
        Bambi-aiheisia koriste-esineitä 
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

However, i havent figured out, how to magnify image from folder in a same way, by using a hyperlink. I do not want to load this image as a part of finished page.

```
<a href=#" rel="magnify[img_at_some_folder]">Click me to see image that is not in this page</a>
```

If someone could point me in correct destination with this i would be very thankful.

[edit]
Basically same thing is done here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm at

> Links that expand a particular "magnify" image

I dont want to load image of Sarah at page, but have the same efect when pressing link "Enlarge Sarah"

Comment: do you want to load the zoomed image in a seperate page?

Comment: or do you want an effect like this http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Comment: Hi Rachel. I would like to have same efect as with the upper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to specify where the image is coming from and give it an id

```
<img id="Virtanen" src="ek.gif" class="imagexample" data-magnifyby="5" style="width:200px; height:150px" />
```

then the hyperlink is as follows

```
<a style="color:blue" href="#" rel="magnify[Virtanen]">Click Me</a>
```

if you want an image that zooms in to an area of that image then use this code:

html:

```
<div id="zt-container" class="zt-container">
<div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-1">
    <img class="zt-current" src="images/image1.jpg" />
    <div class="zt-tag" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-2" data-zoom="5" data-speed="700" data-delay="50" style="top:138px;left:151px;"></div>
    <div class="zt-tag" data-dir="1" data-link="zt-item-3" data-zoom="6" data-speed="700" data-delay="50" style="top:253px;left:520px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-2">
    <img class="zt-current" src="images/image1_1.jpg" />
    <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-1" data-zoom="5" data-speed="500" data-delay="0"></div>
</div>        
<div class="zt-item" data-id="zt-item-3">
    <img class="zt-current" src="images/image2_2.jpg" />
    <div class="zt-tag zt-tag-back" data-dir="-1" data-link="zt-item-1" data-zoom="6" data-speed="500" data-delay="0"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#zt-container').zoomtour({
    // if true the tags are rotated depending on their position
    rotation        : true,
    // zoom out animation easing. Example: easeOutBounce , easeOutBack  
    zoominEasing    : '',  
    // zoom out animation easing
    zoomoutEasing   : ''   
});
```

[Source](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/23/image-zoom-tour/)  [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageZoomTour/)

Comment: Hi. This works if i do load image in page. I edited my original question, sorry for misundesrstanding.

Comment: @E.K.Virtanen i edited my answer. remember if you get a suitable answer, please click the tick beside the answer

Comment: Hi. Ok, your samples are awesome. However, i did mean something else :) However i was able to solve this one with JS. You can see my code and idea of what i ment at http://jsfiddle.net/ekvirtanen/PA6hv/

Comment: @E.K.Virtanen glad you resolved it. other code may come in handy in future.